# data list getting empty

Tags: android, kotlin

```
   val temp1:ArrayList<GetVoiceNoteModel> = arrayListOf()
                        it.data?.voiceNotes?.forEach {
                            temp1.add(GetVoiceNoteModel(id = it.id, userBoardId =  it.userBoardId,userJourneyId=it.userJourneyId,name=it.name))
                        }
                        (fragmentList[0] as NotesFragment).updateVoiceNoteList(temp1)
                      
                        mindFlowAdapterDetail.notifyDataSetChanged()


    fun updateTextNoteList(noteList: ArrayList<GetTextNoteModel> = arrayListOf()) {
        textList.clear()

        for (i in noteList) {
            textList.add(
                TextNoteModel(
                    title = i.name,
                    subTitle = i.notes,
                    noteDate = i.updatedAt.toString(),
                    isExpand = false,
                    noteId = i.id
                )
            )

        }
      
        viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

list getting null after calling   `viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

I tried the debugging

Comment: Which list are you referring to here? The noteList? Where is the exception coming from exactly? Can you share the stacktrace/code?